# Jersey and Spring profiles

Tags: spring, jersey

I should to create Jersey endpoint that will be available only for some spring profiles. I tried to do it in following way:

```
<beans profile="teamcity">
    <bean id="impactRadiusEndpoint" class="com.jingit.api.service.ImpactRadiusEndpoint">
        <constructor-arg ref="impactRadiusQueueProcessor"/>
        <constructor-arg ref="messagesReceiver"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

But when I start up application with some other profiles and call this endpoint, Jersey ignores spring profiles and trying to start up. I find following output in logs:

```
SEVERE: Missing dependency for constructor public     com.jingit.api.service.ImpactRadiusEndpoint(com.jingit.commons.queue.service.QueueProcessor,com.jingit.commons.queue.service.QueueMessagesReceiver) at parameter index 0
SEVERE: Missing dependency for constructor public com.jingit.api.service.ImpactRadiusEndpoint(com.jingit.commons.queue.service.QueueProcessor,com.jingit.commons.queue.service.QueueMessagesReceiver) at parameter index 1
```

Also this issue brokes other endpoints. Does anybody have a idea how to fix it?

Comment: Have you defined the bean `impactRadiusQueueProcessor` for other profiles? Spring is complaining about a missing parameter at index 0 which is the referred bean.

Comment: Yes. Both constructor arguments are available for all profiles